# Keep row by using groupby in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have a df such as

```
Groups  COL1   COL2 COL3
G1      SP1_1  34   130
G1      SP1_2  23   12
G1      SP3_1  43   110
G2      SP1_1  32   40
G2      SP2_1  34   39
G3      SP1_1  32   13
G3      SP2_1  21   140
```

Here I would like to only keep Groups where at least one of the `COL3` value within this group had a `value > 110`.
So here I should only keep
`G1` and `G3`

```
Groups  COL1   COL2 COL3
G1      SP1_1  34   130
G1      SP1_2  23   12
G1      SP3_1  43   110
G2      SP1_1  32   40
G2      SP2_1  34   39
G3      SP1_1  32   13
G3      SP2_1  21   140
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform` + `any`

```
m=df.COL3.gt(110).groupby(df.Groups).transform('any')
df=df[m]
df
Out[149]: 
  Groups   COL1  COL2  COL3
0     G1  SP1_1    34   130
1     G1  SP1_2    23    12
2     G1  SP3_1    43   110
5     G3  SP1_1    32    13
6     G3  SP2_1    21   140
```